# update openssh and openssl on solaris

Tags: solaris, openssl, openssh, nexenta

I got a nexenta system,
I updated openssl to 1.0.1j, which I compiled from source code.
I updated openssh to 6.7, from source code as well, and I get this:

```
root@cteraportal:/root# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014
root@cteraportal:/root# ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.7p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
```

Should I expect the OpenSSL version to be updated on ssh?

Comment: Use `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` when you configure OpenSSH. Autotools will find the correct libraries and headers. `LDFLAGS` should also use `-L/usr/local/lib/64 -m64 -Wl,-R,/usr/local/lib/64` to ensure the correct OpenSSL is used at runtime. For an example see [GitHub | Build-Scripts](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Why can't the OpenSSH configure script detect OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#PROG9) explains the possible cause that might have occured in your case.

Several reasons for problems with the automatic detection exist.

- **OpenSSH** requires at least version 0.9.5a of the **OpenSSL** libraries.
- Sometimes the distribution has installed an older version in the
  system locations that is detected instead of a new one installed.
- The **OpenSSL** library might have been compiled for another CPU or
  another mode (32/64 bits). Permissions might be wrong.

The general answer is to check the `config.log` file generated when running the **OpenSSH** configure script. It should contain the detailed information on why the **OpenSSL** library was not detected or considered incompatible.

However, in your case I find [this information as well](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-6.7).

> Portable OpenSSH now requires openssl 0.9.8f or greater. Older
>   versions are no longer supported.

So as per your `ssh -V` command output, I think you are having a greater version than that is required.

Comment: Found the problem. Specifying "-m64" for compiler and linker fixed it.